# Going overboard on indentation

Tags: discussion, support

Someone edited my code because he felt the indentation was not enough - not other changes

A major code formatting problem here at SO is in my opinion the width of the editor window.

We all know how

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title></title>
            <script>
```

could be indented. I never do. It is preamble and in my strong opinion does not need to be indented at all. When someone then adds 4 (FOUR!) spaces to EVERYTHING, the first line of code is pushed 12 spaces to the right - that is a huge waste of space and will make almost any code not completely visible to the right. Just a few ifs to overflow the right border.

Example on my code which I had to roll back since the edit was accepted:

https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/3502606/4

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // add trim to older IEs
            if (!String.trim) {String.prototype.trim = function() {return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");};}

            window.onload=function() { // onobtrusively adding the submit handler
              document.getelementById("form1").onsubmit=function() { // needs an ID
```

It is a pain, unnecessary and in my case forces readers to scroll

What is the best way to handle this? these edits seems to have been allowed for some reason I do not understand instead of rejected as too minor or invalid or at least proposed to me to agree on.

Comment: I don't see a problem here.  The edit that you rolled back is on your own post, and all he did was add some proper indentation to some HTML code for context.  His other edits are similar.  Reject them as too minor if you must, but these edits look OK to me.

Comment: Maybe I'm just jaded, but I wouldn't call "10 edits" a spree.  Fifty or one-hundred?  Now that's a spree.  Also, the edits I looked at seemed to actually indent code how I would expect it to be indented, and/or fix content as well (such as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/16933492/revisions), which already required scrolling before the edit).

Comment: He has changed several posts from 2 to 4 indents and to indent ALL tags. Doing so pushed the code to the extreme right (I always take care that the code can be read without scrolling) actually hiding some of the comments. 10 edits in one hour, most of which are changing indents from ok to what he perceives as more correct.

Comment: I would argue that the indents are marginally more useful than the benefit of not having to scroll to the right.  In short, there's nothing to see here.

Comment: @mplungjan Links to specific examples please.  I looked at the most recent few and some were a bit minor, but they didn't do what you're describing.

Comment: There were already perfectly good indents. They were just "improvements" to code that was intended to have the indentation they had - see update for example. I am just asking for a generic suggestion and I got it

Comment: It's six of one, half-dozen of the other.  No moderator is going to take action on stuff like this.  Save your flags and meta posts for genuine problems.

Comment: I don't see anything about his edits that requires moderator attention. They are not all brilliant, but overall they seem fine. Not nearly as bad as some of the edits I see.

Comment: It may be trivial to you, Rob, but not to me. We all have our pet peeves, Yours seems to be that I waste your time - mine is people editing my posts without improving them.

Comment: That's not what I said.  Don't pull out your straw man just because you don't like what I said.  You did come here expecting genuine advice, and not necessarily everyone to agree with you, right?

Comment: Then reject it when you see it. Job done.

Comment: I'd say the example edit is harmless; personally, I can't stand seeing all the HTML left-aligned, and I actually like their improvement, although they may have gone a bit overboard with indenting at the top.  I think this just boils down to preference.

Comment: It was not rejected. I had to roll back. If this user does 10 as soon as he gets the reps to do so, it is likely he will continue. Since there are no user-to-user messaging possible, I came here to ask when this would be something to report

Comment: You can @user anyone who edits one of your posts.  But I don't think that's necessary here.

Comment: See that was great advice. I did not know I could @user if the user was not already in a comment or somewhere on the page

Comment: @mplungjan I simply can't stand not properly indented code. I agree with you that too much indenting can also be frustrating, but no indenting sure as hell can be too. That's how I try to contribute a little to the StackExchange network: formatting questions, making questions (or answers) more readable. If you don't like it, just decline the change. I don't think anyone minds proper indented and readable code, or do they?

Comment: My main problem here at SO is the width of the editor window. We all know how `<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title></title><script>` could be indented. I never do. It is preamble and in my strong opinion does not need to be indented at all. When you then add 4 (FOUR!) spaces to EVERYTHING, you push the first line of code 12 spaces to the right - that is a huge waste of space and will make almost any code not completely visible to the right. Just a few ifs to overflow the right border. So I do not agree you make code more readable. SOME code yes, but please pay attention to already indented code.

Comment: PS: HUGE flamewars were started on how many spaces/tabs should be used to indent. I do not like your choice of indentation, please do not force it on my already indented code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While coming to Meta also works, it's generally considered better to just flag a moderator for attention (so as not to call out a specific user on Meta). Flag a post this user edited, and use the "other" reason under "it needs ♦ moderator attention."

No need to do that now, though; mods will see this here.